# Binding WPF ListView to an Object with Child Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-4.0

I have the following object definitions:

```cs
public class FilterItem
{
    public string Type{get;set;}
    public List<string> Items{get;set;}
}

public class FiltersDataContext
{
    public string SearchText{get;set;}
    public List<FilterItem> Filters{get;set;}
}
```

I need to bind a ListView to the `FiltersDataContext.Filters.Items` child collection.

So far my xaml looks like this:

```xml
<ListView Name="ResearchFilters" ItemsSource="{Binding FiltersDataContext.Filters}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel  x:Name="FilterPanel">
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay}" Tag="{Binding Path=Type, Mode=OneWay}" Checked="FilterCheckBox_OnCheck" Unchecked="FilterCheckBox_UnChecked" Click="FilteringResultSet"></CheckBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

However, the ListView only ever displays a single CheckBox. Wondering where I'm going wrong.

Comment: since you have a list of list you either need another `ItemsControl` to handle inner list in `ItemTemplate` or you need to flatten all `Items` into single list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this without using `ListView`, but instead using `ItemsControl`

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CheckBoxItemsControlTemplate}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

And in your resource dictionary, add this

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CheckBoxTemplate">
        <CheckBox  Content="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay}" Tag="{Binding Path=Type, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="CheckBoxItemsControlTemplate">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FiltersDataContext.Filters}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CheckBoxTemplate}">
            </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of ways:

```
   <ListView Name="ResearchFilters" ItemsSource="{Binding Filters}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Tag="{Binding Path=Type, Mode=OneWay}" BorderThickness="0">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>                              
                            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}, Path=Tag, Mode=OneWay}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked" Click="CheckBox_Click"></CheckBox>                               
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

You try binding collection as single value.